# What;s wrong with code which is getting user by email and checking for the password?

Tags: php, database

I 'm newbie to php and I 'm implementing a login system where user enters email and password and check for their existence in database (mysql in phpmyadmin)

the password is encrypted using this function when user first registers :

```
/**
 * Encrypting password
 *
 * @param
 *          password
 *          returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {
    $salt = sha1 ( rand () );
    $salt = substr ( $salt, 0, 10 );
    $encrypted = base64_encode ( sha1 ( $password . $salt, true ) . $salt );
    $hash = array (
            "salt" => $salt,
            "encrypted" => $encrypted 
    );
    return $hash;
}
```

the salt parameter which is the key to decrypt the password is stored in the database with user's info and the decrypt code is :

```
/**
 * Decrypting password
 *
 * @param
 *          salt, password
 *          returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {
    $hash = base64_encode ( sha1 ( $password . $salt, true ) . $salt );

    return $hash;
}
```

the password is decrypted when i go and fetch the user with the email and password entered.

```
/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?" );

    $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $email );

    if ($stmt->execute ()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result ()->fetch_assoc ();
        $stmt->close ();
        $salt = $user ["salt"];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA ( $salt, $user ["encrypted_password"] );
        if ($hash == $password) {
            return $user;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

the problem is when user enters correct email and password still this code returns NULL and i suspect something wrong with handling the password part.

Comment: In your last code block, you're hashing the hash, not the plaintext password... so you end up comparing the password to the hash of a hash...

Comment: Note that you are **hashing** the password, *not* "encrypting" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in these two lines:

```
$hash = $this->checkhashSSHA ( $salt, $user ["encrypted_password"] );
if ($hash == $password) {
```

First, you're hashing the *already hashed* password, instead of the plaintext password.
Then you're comparing that "hash of a hash" to the plaintext password.
So you're doing `hash(hash(pw)) == pw`, when it should be `hash(pw) == hash(pw)`.

You simply have to exchange `$user ["encrypted_password"]` and `$password`:

```
$hash = $this->checkhashSSHA ( $salt, $password );
if ($hash == $user ["encrypted_password"]) {
```

Comment: +1, but just want to add a comment for the OP. For security reason, it is not recommended to return the `$user` with the hashed password and salt. No other code needs these two values, so set them to `null` before you return the `$user`.

Comment: @Siguza i 'm not hashing what is already hashed if you look carefully I 'm calling checkhashSSHA which is the unhashing function which takes the encrypted password and it's salt to return the password as a text and put it in $hash (my mistake it should not be called hash ) then I 'm comparing what is returned to the $password which is entered by the user

Comment: Yes, you're not hashing, you're calling `checkhashSSHA()`.... but if you look carefully, `checkhashSSHA()` is hashing using the `sha1()` function. That's what Siguza meant. This is all correct and you're calling it hash correctly, but you just need to follow this answer and swap the variables and all will be good.

Comment: Yea you and @Siguza are both right I missed something .... my bad Thank you both for help

Comment: You're welcome. It's not really your fault. The name and behaviour of the function are misleading. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Siguza's answer is correct, but your comment to his answer reflects a very reasonable confusion, because the name of the `checkhashSSHA()` function is a bit misleading (i.e. its name does not match its behaviour). A function name that start with "check" should be returning a boolean. I suggest changing it to:

```
/**
 * Decrypting password
 *
 * @param
 *          password, hash, salt
 *          returns boolean
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($password, $hash, $salt) {
    $hash2 = base64_encode ( sha1 ( $password . $salt, true ) . $salt );

    return ($hash == $hash2) ;
}
```

Now change these two lines:

```
$hash = $this->checkhashSSHA ( $salt, $user ["encrypted_password"] );
if ($hash == $password) {
```

to this one line:

```
if (checkhashSSHA($password, $user["encrypted_password"], $salt)) {
```

Now it's clearer and easier to use, and its behaviour matches its name. However, if you care to enhance the naming in your code, here are some suggestions:

- Change `checkhashSSHA()` to `compareHashSSHA()`.
- Change `encrypted_password` in the database to `hashed_password`.

More importantly, the sha1 hashing algorithm is a bit old and not very secure. I recommend changing it to a more secure hashing like sha512. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) and read the comment from Kai Petzke for the full story.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest instead of using the sshhash function you look into the php function password_verify()

Check the docs on that and related functions here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: This does not answer the question at hand.